# Android Ad Mob Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have put Ad Mob ad in my application . I have an Ad Mob  account. Have I put my application in Google Play  in order to receive money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking if your application will be automatically placed in Google Play by placing Ad Mob, or are you asking how to do this?

For you to receive money with Ad Mob, you have to place in you app the advertisements but also upload your application to Google Play, so when people download it and click the advertisements you start generating earns.

For you to upload it, you need to put a name, a description, and screanshots of your app, together with the signed APK.

Comment: now I  haven't put my app in Google Play but Ad Mob displays ads in my app. so know if I put my app in Google Play I will receive money?

Comment: Yes, you will receive money. But first Google has to validate your address, and I believe you have to reach a minimum of 100 dollars for you to be sent your earnings

Comment: thank you. can you give me your email or skype ? if  I will meet question I will ask you?(I am not experienced programmer. I am only 15 years old)

Comment: No problem, my email it´s provided in my user account

Comment: Do you have  apps in Google Play?

Comment: Yeah, for example one called Tragoz which has drink receipes

Comment: I can`t find you email.

Comment: I sent you images can you log in your Email?